# How to set "Y" position in label Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im a trying to change the position of the label, if it is greater than 267, position it above the point, if it is lower than the point, but I can not do it in the formatter function.

I currently achieve it but not programmatically.

[image: Posicion]

What I want to program, is a graph as similar as possible to:

[image: Graph]

If you can help me, thank you very much.

```js
var char = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Title'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Subtitle'
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Title'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Subtitle'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    spline: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {},
      }
    },
    series: {
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          var color = '';
          var serie = this.series.name; 
          if (serie == '2017') {
            color = 'blue';
          } else if (serie == '2018') {
            color = 'orange';
          } else {
            if (this.x == 0) {
              //console.log(serie);
              color = 'red';
            } else {
              color = 'white';
            }
          }

          //console.log(serie);
          //console.log(this.point.y);
          //this.point.attr({x:40});
          //this.point.y.plotY =50;
          //this.point.plotY =-30;

          return '<span style="color:' + color + '">' + this.y + '</span>';
        },
        align: 'center',
        color: 'black',
        rotation: -90, //set label position vertical
        y: -30 // position point
        //if value point is > 267, set label position with Y = 30, else Y = -30
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: '2017',
    data: [275, 270, 276, 265, 271, null],
    color: 'purple'
  }, {
    name: '2018',
    data: [260, 265, null, 270, 263, 266],
    color: 'green',
    lineWidth: 4
  }, {
    type: 'spline',
    name: '2018-Meta',
    data: [267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267],
    marker: {
      lineWidth: 2,
      lineColor: 'red',
      fillColor: 'red',
      symbol: 'circle'
    },
    color: 'red'
  }],

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts `formatter` is a callback JavaScript function to format the data label. So it is not designed to change data label position.

However, you can change data labels position after the chart is loaded using `Highcharts.SVGElement.translate` method which allows you to translate data label as you like. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this;

        chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
          series.points.forEach(function(point) {
            if (point.y >= 267) {
                point.dataLabel.translate(0, -40); // point.dataLabel is a SVGElement
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hdjfbm0t/

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#translate